# How to cleanly generate POCO classes from existing database using Entity Framework 4.3 Code First approach?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.3

I'm following the EF Code-First approach in a project that works against an existing database, to which I'm adding tables as needed.

This database has a number of tables for which I need to generate POCO classes for, and so I was wondering if there was a straight-forward, clean approach, to generating simple POCO classes from the database ... from which I can continue to work with using the general Code-First paradigm?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Entity Framework Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d/) for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just the simple Poco classes without any relations use this T4 template

[Generate entity class from database table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094876/generate-entity-class-from-database-table)