# Choosing the Right Solution for Reverse Engineering with Code First

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

using [ASP.NET Boilerplate](http://aspnetboilerplate.com/)  I have created a solution for a project and I have a pre-existing database for which I wish to use for this project. I wish to use the EF Code First Reverse Engineering tool to map my DB into code.

For best practices however, I'm unsure in which solution I wish to generate the mappings? The tool works simply by right-clicking a solution file and selecting Reverse Engineer Code First and then you're asked to choose a database. So my question is which solution do I use for EF tool? Thanks

EDIT: I believe I'm being misunderstood. I know how to use EF Power Tools already. However I'm not sure which solution should contain the classes which EF Reverse Engineer generates? To use the power tools, you have to right click on one of the solutions. But for best practices which solution should contain the files? Thanks

[image: Files]

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11636359/how-to-cleanly-generate-poco-classes-from-existing-database-using-entity-framewo

Comment: I understand how to use the power tools to generate the classes. However, which solution file (from my screenshot) should the classes be in/make most sense to be in?

Comment: I put mine in the same PROJECT as my context. I then end up moving the generated POCOs to an Entities project and move the DbSets and configs to my EF project. I have customized the templates so the generated namespaces and other settings match. https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.CodeTemplates.CSharp/